# Cannot connect to database using MysqlWorkbench on a specific network. (Works fine everywhere else)

Tags: mysql, networking, mysql-workbench

I've got a database that's hosted on a godaddy server.  I'm using MysqlWorkbench for manual access while I'm designing a webapp.  I can connect from home no problem, but I can't connect from my work.  I'm using workbench because Phpmyadmin on godaddy is buggy and causes the browser tab to crash frequently.  The work network is set up as a public wifi network, so I assume that's the problem.  The MysqlWorkbench error (below) is not particularly helpful.  Any ideas on what I can do to make workbench work or ideas on what I should be looking at to figure out why I'm having the problem?

MysqlWorkbench Error (username and server address removed):

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'USER' from your host to server at SERVER:3306:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER' (4)
```

I'm using the exact same connection that works fine elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps port 3306 is not available for use in your work network. Can you ssh to your godaddy server from work?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench **can't** run without a MySQL server. Just install a MySQL community server, any version (like, 5.17 MSI for example,) and then Workbench.

You should now be able to use MySQL Workbench!